# using dialog inside of onitemclicklistener, getting unfortunately stopped

Tags: android, onitemclick

I'm trying to create dialog inside of `onitemclicklistener`.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int position, long arg3) {                
    String data = values[position];
    Dialog d = new Dialog(null);
    TextView t = new TextView(null);
    t.setText(data);
    d.setTitle("Okey!");
    d.show();
}
```

There is no problem with other things. Problem is `dialog`. I know because when I remove `dialog` everything is done. I've looked [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#Dialog%28android.content.Context%29). That say something about `context` class. I'm newbie and I can't get what is that. What is the problem? and how can i use dialog, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Dialog` and `TextView` constructors should be passed a `Context` object, but you are passing them `null`.

Since your activity extends `Context`, you may pass an instance of your activity.

Assuming the name of your activity is `MainActivity` then you would do this:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
//...
```